# How can I get my Image to be displayed using Java?

Tags: java, swing

Well basically my image will not display, i'm almost certain it's my file path
 (‪" C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\card.png" is what the image properties say is the file path but unless i put double slashes it confuses them for escape sequences. ) If someone has the answer it will be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class IDK extends JFrame {



public static void main(String args[]) {

    new IDK();


}

public IDK(){

        notsure();

        }
public void notsure(){


    setBounds(420,100,440,400);
    setTitle("Frame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Tell me something");
    JLabel image = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("New Text");
    JTextField text = new JTextField("Insert text",30);
    image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\card.jpg"));
    panel.add(label1,image);
    panel.add(text);
    add(panel);
    validate();
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 
    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Yes, "\" will need to be escaped, you can use `/` on Windows and the JVM will automagically correct for them

Comment: Are you sure `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\card.png` or `C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\card.jpg` .? You have mentioned different one in question different in code.. PLease make sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with using "\" so long as it's escaped, as you have done, if your prefer you can use `/` instead and on Windows the JRE will correct for it.

How ever, you should be adding the `image` separately, for example...

```
image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\card.jpg"));
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(image);
```

The way you are doing it now assumes that `image` is a layout constraint for `label1`, which it isn't.

You should try and avoid using absolute paths and learn to use relative paths and/or embed the resources within the application context, this makes it easier to locate these resources at runtime.

Comment: how do i embed the resources within the application context? by the way thank you, it worked :)

Comment: That depends, what IDE are you using?  Generally it means copying your resources into the `src` directory of your project and using `Class#getResource` to retrieve them...

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your project and call it i.e. 'resources' and put your image in that folder. This will ensure that given image is on your classpath and can be easily accessed.

Then you can just do :

```
new ImageIcon("resources/card.jgp")
```

Problem with accessing outside resources is that special characters needs to be escaped and also if you export the project and give it to someone else, he/she will not have the image required by software ;)

Comment: Don't, ever, reference the `src` directory from within your code, it will not exist once the program is packaged.  This is also dependent on the IDE or build approach the OP is using, for example, Netbeans would like the `resources` directory within the `src` directory, Eclipse can be do both (I think) and Maven is another story all together...

Comment: Also, `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the resource is file on the OS disk, which if the resource is embedded within the program Jar, it will no longer be, making it inaccessible once the application is packaged...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes the src will not exists so you are right :). OP did not state if he uses maven or not and what IDE he is using. however i do not think that any IDE will object having resources folder under src ?. As of ImageIcon that is also true but if OP wants to use the image after packing to jar i.e. he can modify this to be ImagEIcon(getClass().getResource(""); isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, an embedded resource is a better solution, just make sure the OP knows the difference between `ImageIcon(String)` and `ImageIcon(URL)` ;) - also I think the issue the OP is actually having is the fact that they haven't actually added the image to the UI